# Counting genetic mutations in dictionary using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, bioinformatics

I have data in this format:

>abc12

ATCGACAG
>def34
ACCGACG

etc.

I have stored each gene into a dictionary with the lines beginning with > as values. So the dictionary is something like {'abc12':'ATCGACAG', etc.}

Now I want to be able to compare each gene, so that it counts the number of A's, T's, C's, or G's at each site.

The only thing I can come up with is to break the dictionary into lists for each nucleotide site and using zip() with a counter. Is this the best way, and if so, how do I break the dictionary into a list for each site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('ATCGACAG')
Counter({'A': 3, 'C': 2, 'G': 2, 'T': 1})
>>> Counter('ACCGACG')
Counter({'C': 3, 'A': 2, 'G': 2})
```

Comment: I want to be able to count as if it were an alignment. E.g.
at site one, both genes have an A, but at site two, one has a C and one has a T. 

So the output would be something like:
1: 5 A's, 2 C's
2: 3 G's, 4 A's

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason not to use Biopython?

```
from Bio import AlignIO
alignment =AlignIO.read("alignment.fas", "fasta")
n=0
while n<len(alignment[0]):
    A=alignment[:,n].count('A')
    C=alignment[:,n].count('C')
    G=alignment[:,n].count('G')
    T=alignment[:,n].count('T')
    gap=alignment[:,n].count('-')

    print "at position %s there are %s A's, %s C's, %s G's, %s T's and %s gaps" % (n, A, C, G, T, gap)
    n=n+1
```

Make sure you have a real alignment (i.e. sequences are the same length).
p.s. I apologize for the ugly formatting of the print statement...

this returns

```
at position 0 there are 2 A's, 0 C's, 0 G's, 0 T's and 0 gaps
at position 1 there are 0 A's, 1 C's, 0 G's, 1 T's and 0 gaps
at position 2 there are 0 A's, 2 C's, 0 G's, 0 T's and 0 gaps
at position 3 there are 0 A's, 0 C's, 2 G's, 0 T's and 0 gaps
at position 4 there are 2 A's, 0 C's, 0 G's, 0 T's and 0 gaps
at position 5 there are 0 A's, 2 C's, 0 G's, 0 T's and 0 gaps
at position 6 there are 1 A's, 0 C's, 0 G's, 0 T's and 1 gaps
at position 7 there are 0 A's, 0 C's, 2 G's, 0 T's and 0 gaps
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 = "ATCGACAG"
s2 = "ACCGACG"   
alignment = [s1[i] if s1[i] == s2[i] else "-" for i in range(len(min([s1,s2],key=len)))]
print "".join(alignment)
A-CGAC-
```