# Iterating through tuples to count values in list

Tags: python, tuples

I have a dictionary with multiple genes. The tuple(zip()) gives the nucleotide at each site. E.g. (A, A, A), (T, T, G), etc. I'm trying to count the number of nucleotides at each site. Such that site 1 shows 3 A's, and site 2 shows 2 T's and 1 G. When I run my code, it is only adding to A and nothing else.

```
List = tuple(zip(*myDict.values()))

A = 0
T = 0
G = 0
C = 0

site = 0

for value in List:
    site +=1
    if 'A':
        A += 1
    elif 'T':
        T += 1
    elif 'G':
        G += 1
    else:
        C =+ 1

print 'Site:', site
print 'A:', A
print 'T:', T
print 'G:', G
print 'C:', C
```

Comment: Related: [Parse positions of dictionary values into a list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12633774) [Counting genetic mutations in dictionary using python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12631052) and [Using regex to transform data into a dictionary in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12611491)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can (again), best use `collections.Counter()`:

```
[Counter(site) for site in zip(*myDict.values())]
```

This will create a list of gene counts per site.

Demonstration:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> myDict = {'abc':'AGCTAC', 'def': 'AGGTAC', 'ghi':'AGGTAG'}
>>> result = [Counter(site) for site in zip(*myDict.values())]
>>> result
[Counter({'A': 3}), Counter({'G': 3}), Counter({'G': 2, 'C': 1}), Counter({'T': 3}), Counter({'A': 3}), Counter({'C': 2, 'G': 1})]
>>> result[0]  # genes at site 0
Counter({'A': 3})
>>> result[2]  # genes at site 2
Counter({'G': 2, 'C': 1})
```

Answer (score 6):

use `Counter()`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lis=[('A', 'A', 'A'), ('T', 'T', 'G')]
>>> Counter(y for x in lis for y in x)
Counter({'A': 3, 'T': 2, 'G': 1})
```

Alternatively as @Steven Rumbalski suggested, using`itertools.chain()` instead of the generator expression:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> Counter(chain(*lis))
Counter({'A': 3, 'T': 2, 'G': 1})
```

and for separate counters at individual sites see Martijn Pieters's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642997/846892)

Comment: Or `Counter(itertools.chain(*lis))`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski does it have any advantage over generator expression?

Comment: I doubt it has any performance advantage.  Whenever I see nested generator expressions I need slow down to read it.  `chain` puts a nice name on what is really happening.  Of course, readability is subjective.

Answer (score 6):

ITYM

```
for value in List:
    site +=1
    if value == 'A':
        A += 1
    elif value == 'T':
        T += 1
    elif value == 'G':
        G += 1
    else:
        C +=1
```

But there are better ways; see the other answers.

Besides, you sould not call your list `List`; uppercase names are reserved for classes. `list` is not good as well, as it hides the built-in `list()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
A = List.count("A")
B = List.count("C")
...
```

btw List is a terrible variable name

Comment: This will iterate the full list for each letter.  Better to use `collections.Counter`.

Comment: I agree and +1'd the counter answers .. but this is nice and very clear what is going on (not that counter necessarily isnt)